# Submitting Spark Jobs to Spark Cluster

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn, hadoop2, high-availability, spark-jobserver

I am a complete novice in Spark and just started exploring more on this. I have chosen the longer path by not installing hadoop using any CDH distribution and i have installed Hadoop from Apache website and setting the config file myself to understand more on the basics.

I have setup a 3 node cluster (All node are VM machine created from ESX server).
I have setup High Availability for both Namenode and ResourceManager by using zookeeper mechanism. All three nodes are being used as DataNode as well.

The Following Daemons are Running across All three Nodes

```
Daemon in Namenode 1          Daemon In Namenode 2       Daemon in Datanode         
8724 QuorumPeerMain           22896 QuorumPeerMain       7379 DataNode   
13652 Jps                     23780 ResourceManager      7299 JournalNode
9045 DFSZKFailoverController  23220 DataNode             7556 NodeManager
9175 DataNode                 23141 NameNode             7246 QuorumPeerMain
9447 NodeManager              27034 Jps                  9705 Jps
8922 NameNode                 23595 NodeManager
8811 JournalNode              22955 JournalNode
9324 ResourceManager          23055 DFSZKFailoverController
```

I have setup HA for NN and RM in NameNode 1 & 2.
The Nodes are of very minimum Hardware configuration (4GM RAM each and 20GB Disk Space) , But these are just for testing purpose. so i guess its ok.

I have installed Spark (Compatible version to my installed Hadoop 2.7) in NameNode 1. I am able to start Spark-shell locally and perform basic scala command to create RDD and perform some Actions over it. I also manage to test run SparkPi example as Yarn-Cluster and Yarn-Client deployment Mode. All works well and good.

Now my problem is , In real time scenario , We are going to write (Java, scala or py) based code in our local machine (Not in the nodes which form the Hadoop Cluster). Lets say i have another machine in same network as my HA Cluster is.How do i submit my Job to the Yarn-Cluster (Lets say i want to try submitting SparkPi) example from a host not in HA to the Yarn RM , How do i do this ?

I believe , SPARK has to be installed in machine where i am writing my code from (Is my assumption correct) and No spark needs to be installed in the HA Cluster. I also want to get the output of the submitted job back to the Host from where it was submitted. I have no idea what needed to be done to make this work.

I have heard of **Spark JobServer** , Is this what i need to get this all up and running ? I believe you guys can help me out with this confusion. I just could not find any document which clearly specify the steps to follow to get this done. Can i submit a job from Windows based machine to my HA cluster setup in unix environment ?

Answer (score 0):

Spark JobServer provides rest interface for your requirement. Apart from that there are other features.

See https://github.com/spark-jobserver/spark-jobserver for more information.

Comment: Can you confirm if i need to install this at my client machine or in Hadoop Cluster . Also i believe Spark must be installed only in client machine if am not wrong

Comment: Yes, the spark must be installed on the machine where you are going to run Spark JobServer. But it is not necessary that SJS to run inside the cluster unless there are strong network restrictions.

Comment: Do you have any reference to sites which explain how to submit spark jobs from remote machine to Yarn Cluster. Majority of post i found is using localhost (submitting jobs to standalone server)

Comment: No, I have not used yarn. There is documentation about EMR and SJS https://github.com/spark-jobserver/spark-jobserver/blob/master/doc/EMR.md It might be useful for you. Yarn client documentation is here https://github.com/spark-jobserver/spark-jobserver/blob/master/doc/yarn.md

Answer (score 0):

In order to submit spark jobs to the cluster your machine have to become a "gateway node". That basically means you have hadoop binaries/libraries/configs installed on that machine, but there are no hadoop daemons running on it.

Once you have it setup, you should be able to run hdfs commands against your cluster from that machine (like hdfs dfs -ls /), submit yarn applications to the cluster (yarn jar /opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH/jars/hadoop-examples.jar pi 3 100).

After that step you can install spark on your gateway machine and start submitting spark jobs. If you are going to use Spark-on-yarn, this is the only machine spark needs to be installed on.

You (your code) is the one responsible for getting the output of the job. You could choose to save the result in HDFS (the most common choice), print it to the console, etc... Spark's History Server is for debugging purposes.

Comment: thanks for your inputs.Just to clarify , By "Gateway Node" machine you are referring to machines where developers will write application code and submit it to Yarn-Cluster. Each of these machine must have hadoop installed (But not necessary) to start all daemons.  And Gateway Machine refer to Namenode 1 in my scenario where i have SPARK installed in the cluster

Comment: Correct. Gateway machine is the one where a developers will submit the job. Each of these machines must have hadoop installed, but it will not run any hadoop daemons.

Comment: So this process skips the need of Spark-Job Server ?

Comment: What do you meean by Spark-Job Server? Is it Spark History Server? Spark History Server is a web server that lets you browse job info for jobs executed in the past. If you don't need that, there is no need to install it.